Factoring a small sample size into a larger sample size for the purpose of simulation
Let's say a left-handed baseball pitcher has faced 153 batters — 150 of which bat right-handed, and 3 of which bat left-handed. It is widely accepted that a left-handed pitcher will perform better against left-handed batters, and somewhat worse against right-handed batters, so in this case the vast majority of the data skews towards the pitcher's weakness — lefty vs. righty.
Of the 150 right-handed batters the pitcher has faced, 30 have gotten a base hit for a .200 batting average against the pitcher. Against the 3 left-handed batters, the pitcher struck out 2 and retired the third batter on a fly ball, so the batting average in this very small sample size is .000.
Now, let's say I want to simulate a 9-inning game in which every batter on the opposing team bats left-handed. If I were to only consider the small sample size of 3 left-handed batters, the pitcher would theoretically allow no hits and strike out 18 batters for a remarkable perfect game. We know this is entirely unrealistic.
Short of tossing out the small sample size and using only the data sampled against right-handed hitters, how would I go about factoring in the results from the very small sample size?
I'm assuming that when both sample sizes are sufficiently large, I can use the left vs left data for simulation without considering the left vs right data. But at what point would one need to factor in the data from both samples to best simulate results? For example, if the left vs left data makes up 33% of the combined sample, and the left vs right data makes up 67% of the data, should the simulation consider both samples, or only the left vs left sample? In other words, at what point would one need to factor in the larger sample size when simulating a scenario that only tests the smaller sample size case?
Any pointers here?
